# How do you make a ContentPage fullscreen?

Tags: xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms 1.3+, how do you make a `ContentPage` fullscreen?
The most basic exemple of a `ContentPage` is the one provided upon creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable project.

```
public App (){
    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new ContentPage {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

More info (Android): https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 1):

Your ContentPage is fullscreen. Only the content in your ContentPage does not fill your entire screen. 
You can try something like this:

```
HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
```

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't go fullscreen. Here is more information about the real Fullscreen on Android as an exemple.
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html
There should be no titlebar

Comment: To hide the titlebar you can use. MainMenuPage mainMenuPage = new MainMenuPage (); NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (mainMenuPage, false); await Navigation.PushAsync (mainMenuPage);

Comment: The real fullscreen doesn't show the titlebar AND the notification bar (where the time is). Your code works, but not like the real Android fullscreen as shown in the previous link.

Figure 1 is normal and figure 3 is the real fullscreen:
https://developer.android.com/images/training/imm-states.png

Answer (score 0):

your content page is fullscreen .  You can check by changing the background color of your content page. Try this following code

**BackgroundColor = Color.White**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 in making a full screen is by hiding the Navigation Bar. This can be controlled while Navigating to the View.

```
FullScreenVideoPlayerPage fullScreenVideoPage = new FullScreenVideoPlayerPage();
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(fullScreenVideoPage, false);
await Navigation.PushAsync(fullScreenVideoPage);
```

Remember to use async keyword in Method Signature when using await.

```
private async void FullScreenVideoPlayerPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Step 2 is to hide the Android Status Bar. But seems this is not standard with Android. I was not fully successful in completely hiding this bar. But I could hide the status icons by:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;

//......

// Call this method from the constructor after InitializeComponent ();
public void HideStatusBar()
{
var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
var window = activity.Window;
var attrs = window.Attributes;
attrs.Flags |= Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;
window.Attributes = attrs;

window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);
window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

var decorView = window.DecorView;

var uiOptions =
    (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable |
    (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation |
    (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen |
    (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
    (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen |
    (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.Immersive;

decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (Android.Views.StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;

window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Hidden;
}
```